# Custom Dialog xml

Tags: android, dialog

I want to add a custom Dialog, but I have problems creating a xml like I want..

Here what I imagine:

[IMAGE][TEXT]

[SCROLLABLETEXT]

[BUTTON][BUTTON][BUTTON]

And my current xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgMentor"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/changelogicon" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvSubject"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="--"
            android:textColor="#FFF"
            android:textSize="20px" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/layout_root"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="10dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvExplanation"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="7dip"
            android:text="--"
            android:textColor="#FFF" />
    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:baselineAligned="true" >


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Image, text and scrollable text looking great, but if the text in the middle gets too long and become scrollable, my buttons are gone..

What did I do wrong?

EDIT:
my Solution:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgIcon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/changelogicon" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvSubject"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imgIcon"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgIcon"
        android:text="--"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:textSize="20px" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/layout_root"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imgIcon"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvExplanation"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="7dip"
            android:text="--"
            android:textColor="#FFF" />
    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: tried putting scrollview outside your main linear layout..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [`RelativeLayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html) rather than a `LinearLayout` as the top-level element in your view hierarchy. `LinearLayout`s don't do very well at handling this sort of "fill the middle" scenario.

With a `RelativeLayout` you can align your buttons with the bottom, your text/image with the top and then align your `ScrollView` to be below the text/image and above the buttons, stretching it accordingly.

Take a look at the ["Hello RelativeLayout"](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-relativelayout.html) tutorial for more info.

Quick SO tip: If you increase your accept rate, more people are likely to answer your question.